# function presave action to update item

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, jsom

I'm attempting to update a list item upon clicking save on my newform.  I think I'm close, but  perhaps not as I'm really new to this.  My wheels have been spinning for a few days.

I am attempting to user the PreSaveAction() function to accomplish this.  Setting my list item to 'nextnumber'.

Is what I want to do possible?

Here is my code:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

 var clientContext = null;
 var web = null;
 ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(AutoGenerate, "sp.js");
    
 function AutoGenerate() {
 
     var targetListItem;
     clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
     web = clientContext.get_web();
     var list = web.get_lists().getById(_spPageContextInfo.pageListId);
     var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
     camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query></Query></View>');
     this.listItems = list.getItems(camlQuery);
     clientContext.load(listItems);
     clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onListItemsLoadSuccess),
         Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
 }
    
 function onListItemsLoadSuccess(sender, args) {
     var itemId = 1;  
     var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(); 
     var targetList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('AutoQuoteNumberTest');
     targetListItem = targetList.getItemById(itemId);
     clientContext.load(targetListItem, 'NextQuoteNumber', 'Title','ID','Modified','NextQuoteNum_x0020_Available','Next_x0020_Number');
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
     
 }



  function onQuerySucceeded() {
     var AutoIncremental = targetListItem.get_item('NextQuoteNumber');
     var nextnumber = targetListItem.get_item('Next_x0020_Number');
     var lastnumber = targetListItem.get_item('NextQuoteNum_x0020_Available');
     alert(AutoIncremental);
     alert(nextnumber);
     alert(lastnumber);
       $("input[title^='Quote Number']").val(AutoIncremental);
     $("input[title^='Quote Number']").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
   }

function MyPreSaveAction()
{
PreSaveAction();
}

function PreSaveAction()
{
targetListItem.set_item('NextQuoteNum_x0020_Available', nextnumber);
return false;
}

 function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
     alert('request failed ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
 }


</script>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: which list item are you trying to update, older?

Comment: I've added a couple screenshot details to my original post.  I'm basically pulling 'nextquotenumber' from the autoquotenumbertest list to be used in the quote number field.  *This is happening successfully.

Next what I need to have happen to keep the number updating is to have the nextnumber become the lastnumber column.   These fields are used to generate 'nextquotenumber'.  Hopefully on submit.

FYI, I was doing this all with sharepoint workflow on prem, but have recently migrated to sharepoint online and the flows do not kick off quick enough to generate a new number in time.